# UserManager.IsInRoleAsync and UserManager.GetRolesAsync do not agree with each other

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity

Suddenly, a query to UserManager.IsInRoleAsync is returning 'false' for a user when it should return 'true'.  Querying UserManager.GetRolesAsync for the user confirms that UserManager.IsInRoleAsync should indeed be returning 'true'.
Here is a screenshot from the debugger that illustrates the problem:

[image]

I'm completely baffled. 
I am using Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core (2.2.0.0).

Comment: Could you share how did you get the `user`?I could get the role and return true by using your code.

Comment: And how did you add role to the user?What is your Startup.cs like?

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well. Did you ever figure out what was going on here?

Comment: Hmm, I did get passed the issue, but I'm sorry to say that I don't recall exactly what the issue was, and I don't have access to this code-base any longer.

Answer (score 2):

This could be caused by one of 2 problems in my experience:

1. I believe IsInRoleAsync requires the user to be authenticateds in order to work.
2. If you migrated your roles from the old ASP.NET membership schema, the  script microsoft provides for migrating the data into the ASPNetRoles table does not populate the column **NormalizedName**. IsInRoleAsync is checking against this field for the roles. Populate that field and it should return true.